# How to write unit test for go Web api

Tags: go

I am writing an unit test for golang web API.
I have a API like **domain.com/api/user/current**.
This API will return information user's logged in.
I use **http.NewRequest** for make a request to this API. But it's doesn't work.

So how to make a self call to this API with permission is logged?

```
func TestGetCurrentUserLogged(t *testing.T) {
    assert := assert.New(t)

    var url = "http://example.com/user/current";
    req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, url, nil)
    client := &http.Client{}
    //req.Header.Add("Cookie", "")//
    res, _ := client.Do(req)
    if res.StatusCode == http.StatusBadGateway {
        assert.True(false)
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    defer res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Error 1 API: %v", err.Error())
    }
    var response map[string]interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &response)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Error 2 API:%v", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Comment: "But it's doesn't work." is not a problem description. Please be more specific.

Comment: You have a permission problem?

Comment: Now, I tried make a call to login service then get cookie then add it into header requests

Comment: Your test, as written, will only work if the server is running. I don't know if you're starting it somewhere else in your tests, but this makes the tests unnecessarily heavy; instead of using a Client to make the requests, you can just pass your request and a `httptest.ResponseRecorder` directly to your HTTP handlers to test them.

Comment: Yep, you correct, my server not running, I only run my tests when my server is started.
So, what the best way to make my server running when I started my tests?

Answer (score 0):

This is I test my servers...though I believe this to be more functional testing, which is more like what you seem to want to do above. I've added comments in the code so that you get an idea of what is going on. Of course you'd have to take this and modify it to your needs.

```
type payload struct {
    WhateverElse interface{}
    Error        error
}

func TestSite(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
    defer cancel()
    // I'm using the Bone router in this example but can be replaced with most routers
    myRouter := bone.New()
    myRouter.GetFunc("/foo/:bar", routes.WipeCache)
    myRouter.NotFoundFunc(routes.NotFound)
    n := negroni.New()
    n.UseHandler(wrappers.DefaultHeaders(myRouter))
    // start an instance of the server on port 8080
    // to run different tests in different functions, change the port
    srv := &http.Server{Addr: ":8080", Handler: n}
    on := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    go func(on chan struct{}) {
        on <- struct{}{}
        log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
    }(on)
    // shutdown the server when i'm done
    srv.Shutdown(ctx)
    // the channel on is not really needed, but I like to have it to make sure srv.ListenAndServe() has had enough time to warm up before I make a requests. So i block just a tiny bit.
    <-on

    // create the client requests to test the server
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: 1 * time.Second,
    }

    // Test logic
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://localhost:8080/foo/bar", nil)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("An error occurred. %v", err)
    }
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("An error occurred. %v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    ctx.Done()

    if status := resp.StatusCode; status != http.StatusOK {
        t.Errorf("Status code differs. Expected %d .\n Got %d instead", http.StatusOK, status)
    }
    var data payload
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("An error occurred. %v", err)
    }
    json.Unmarshal(body, &data)

    if data.Error != nil {
        t.Errorf("An error occurred. %v", err)
    }
}
```